# how to calculate percentage mysql window function

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

so i have table structure like this

```
CREATE TABLE sales(
    id_order VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    fiscal_year INT NOT NULL,
    sale DECIMAL(14,2) NOT NULL,
    location varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_order,fiscal_year)
);

INSERT INTO sales(id_order,fiscal_year,sale, location)
VALUES(1,2016,100, 'Jakarta'),
      (2,2017,150, 'Bekasi'),
      (3,2018,200, 'Depok'),
      (4,2016,150, 'Jakarta'),
      (5,2017,100, 'Bekasi'),
      (6,2018,200, 'Depok'),
       (7,2016,200, 'Jakarta'),
      (8,2017,150, 'Bekasi'),
      (9,2018,250, 'Depok');

SELECT * FROM sales;
```

on this case, i want to make a percentage for the amount of sale and count of id_order over location

based on my case, this is the expected results :

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+----------------------+
| Location |  sale(kg) |  sale (%) |   count(id_order)  |  count(id_order) (%) |
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+----------------------+
| Jakarta  |       450 | 30 %      |                  3 | 33,33%               |
| Bekasi   |       400 | 26,67 %   |                  3 | 33,33%               |
| Depok    |       650 | 43,33 %   |                  3 | 33,33%               |
| Total    |      1500 | 100 %     |                  9 | 100%                 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

i've try with this syntax

```
SELECT 
    location,
    sum(sale)/ sum(sale) over()
    sum(count(id_order)) / sum(count(id_order)) over()
FROM
    sales
    group by location;
```

but it's said 
Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'fiddle_WKQHEMOVYSDKFWLXWXHB.sales.sale' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1924f09b991b4ddb5bfaa1390b5d61c3)

Comment: sorry typo, i want make a percentage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`SUM .. OVER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  location AS `Location`, 
  SUM(sale) OVER (PARTITION BY location) AS `sale(kg)`,
  SUM(sale) OVER (PARTITION BY location) / SUM(sale) OVER () * 100 AS `sale (%)`,
  COUNT(id_order) OVER (PARTITION BY location) AS `count(id_order)`,
  COUNT(id_order) OVER (PARTITION BY location) / COUNT(id_order) OVER () * 100 AS `count(id_order) (%)`
FROM sales
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', SUM(sale), 100, COUNT(id_order), 100
FROM sales
```

... or you can use the following solution using [`GROUP BY` with `WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(location, 'Total') AS `Location`, 
  SUM(sale) AS `sale(kg)`,
  SUM(sale) / (SELECT SUM(sale) FROM sales) * 100 AS `sale (%)`, 
  COUNT(id_order) AS `count(id_order)`,
  COUNT(id_order) / (SELECT COUNT(id_order) FROM sales) * 100 AS `count(id_order) (%)`
FROM sales 
GROUP BY location WITH ROLLUP;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c6798687448292cf4a2a026a2b397ab)

Comment: oh i forgot sir, can you give me an advice, so in my real case, the location are in the different table, with same code_order as the primary key, can you give me a little help for this case

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil - can you update the demo to see the structure? Looks like you need a inner join with the different table and the sale table.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT location,
                     sum(sale) sale,
                     count(id_order) cnt
              FROM sales
              group by location with rollup )
SELECT COALESCE(t1.location, 'TOTAL') location,
       t1.sale `sale (kg)`,
       t1.sale / t2.sale * 100 `sale (%)`,
       t1.cnt `count(id_order)`,
       t1.cnt / t2.cnt * 100 `count(id_order) (%)`
FROM cte t1, cte t2
WHERE t2.location is null
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b14429777609a9ce18c500345ec5a2e8)

Comment: thankyou very much sir for your help, have a nice day